# nodejs couchapp does not link css file

Tags: node.js, couchdb, couchapp

I have made a couchdb design document which works perfectly on the following url
`http://localhost:5984/db/_design/app/index.html`
Now the problem is i am trying to fetch the page contents and display it from node js but only the html page is displayed the linked css and js files are not working and when i tried to narrow down the problem i found that the css and js files are suppose to have the login credentials of the couchdb and is not linking I even tried adding the auth header in the response parameter but still no luck

```
var http = require('http');

var json;
var root = new Buffer("admin:pass").toString('base64');
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
res.setHeader('Authorization', root);
res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type':'text/html' });
couchPage();
res.end(json);  
}).listen(8080);

function couchPage() {
var options = {
    hostname: 'localhost',
    port: 5984,
    path: '/db/_design/app/index.html',
    auth: 'admin:pass',
    method: 'GET'
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        json = chunk;
    });
});

req.end();
}
```

could any one please guide me where am i wrong

Answer (score 0):

I think this has nothing to do with couchdb authorization. The problem is that you do not perform any routing on your nodejs server. That is, the browser makes a request to localhost:8080 and receives the content of /db/_design/app/index.html as an answer. Now, the browser detects a link to a stylesheet, say "style.css". It performs a request to localhost:8080/style.css but your nodejs server simply ignores the "style.css" part of the request. Instead, the client will receive the content of /db/_design/app/index.html again!

If you want to serve attachments of your design document through nodejs, you have to parse the request first and then retrieve the corresponding document from couchdb. However, I don't think that you actually want to do this. Either you want to use couchdb in a traditional way behind nodejs (not directly accessible from the client) and then you would just use it as a database with your html (or template) files stored on disk. Or you want to directly expose couchdb to the client and make nodejs listen to events via the couchdb _changes feed.